# Picking out multiple lines from a file at once

Tags: bash, awk

Not sure if this is possible but here goes-

I have a list of numbers.

```
cat list
```

Output-

```
1
22
53
75
```

And I have a secondary file with 500 lines (file.txt).
I want to pick out the 1st, 22nd, 53rd and 75th lines from that file.

What I've currently tried is-

```
for i in `cat list`; do awk "NR==$i" file.txt ; done
```

This works but it's really REALLY slow (my actual files have 50k+ lines).
I was wondering if there was a more efficient solution. Maybe a way to read the list and bring out all those lines in one process rather than 4 processes.

Comment: `sed -n -e '1p' -e '22p' -e '53p' -e '75p' filename`. Or, looping `for i in $list; do sed -n "${i}p" file.txt; done`

Comment: If `list` is a file (e.g. `list.txt`), then use a `while read -r num; do sed -n "${num}p" file.txt; done < "$list.txt"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say list contains these lines:

```
$ cat list
1
22
53
75
```

sed+bash based approach:

```
$ a=($(<list))
# ^^ a will contain contents of 'list' in individual array elements.
$ sed -n "${a[*]/%/p;}" file.txt
# ^^ "${a[*]/%/p;}" will expand to "1p;22p;53p;75p;"
```

awk based approach:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++; next;} (FNR in a)' list file.txt
# Array 'a' will contain 1 at indices equal to lines in 'list'
# Then match line numbers for second file, which are indices of 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually implemented a tail -n | head -n approach since that turned out to be faster.

Comment: `tail | head` is faster for a single line. But I was not sure how it would fare for a list of lines (and thereby a for loop in bash).

Comment: The awk script above is the ONLY way to do this. It'll be more robust, portable, and orders of magnitude faster than any other approach. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for SOME of the reasons to avoid a loop.

Comment: @EdMorton: Assuming that we have bash that supports process substitution, how does [Cyrus's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39053789/793796) below fare? I guess, that one is robust too. Do we have any ready data for speed for the awk and (his) sed based approaches?

Comment: OMG I take back everything. @EdMorton was right. That loop-less awk is perfect. it made my script overall about 15 times faster since this part of the problem was the rate limiting process. Thanks a ton! I must remeber this technique from now on.

Comment: @anishsane in cygwin on bash using a 1 million line input file, with a 100,000 line file of randomly generated line numbers (courtesy of`awk 'BEGIN {for (i=1;i<=100000;i++) print int(rand()*999999)+1}' > lineNrs`) [Cyrus's sed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39053789/793796) ran for about 20 minutes and then froze after producing 96,622 lines of output. My best guess is there's a limit on how long a sed script can be and 100000 lines is too long but idk. Your awk solution completed in a couple of seconds with time output of `real    0m2.964s; user    0m2.886s; sys     0m0.077s`.

Comment: @anishsane I re-ran the test on the same 1 million input line file but now with a line numbers file of 10,000 line nrs and sed completed with `time` output `real    4m0.694s; user    4m0.146s; sys     0m0.185s` while awk completed with `time` output of `real    0m2.527s; user    0m2.464s; sys     0m0.061s` so in this case  it took **4 minutes for sed** vs **2 seconds for awk**.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed and GNU bash:

```
sed -n -f <(sed 's/.*/&p/' numbers.txt) file.txt
```

Comment: `-f` was a great idea, compared to my `bash+sed` approach. It would work for larger `number.txt` file (since it will not cross `MAX_ARG_STRLEN`).

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk`, if your list is very small

```
awk -v nums="^($(paste -s -d"|" list))$" 'NR~nums' file
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `head` and `tail` to achieve this.

Usng head will return the first *n* lines of a file, tail will return the last *n* lines, so if I want to get line 5:

```
cat file | head -n 5 | tail -n 1
```

Should do the trick.

ETA - probably worth pointing out that you cannot pass 0 as a parameter to the .n option, lines are numbered 1 and upwards as opposed to 0 and upwards.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: `head` and `tail` can accept file input.. this is a case of useless use of cat.. `head -n 5 file | tail -n 1`